# Unexpected behavior return a value from a std::bitset inside a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use the value from a std::bitset inside of a lambda function but I am experiencing unexpected behavior:

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](unsigned int param)
    {   
        std::bitset<10> bits(param);
        std::cout << "inside lambda bits[8] = " << bits[8] << std::endl; 
        return bits[8];
    };

    // 0x11c is 1_0001_1100 in binary
    auto result = lambda(0x11c);
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect the value of result to be one since result is of type bool which can be copied from the local stack but instead the output is the following:

```
inside lambda bits[8] = 1
result = 0
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: I do not use `std::bitset` very often, but this question intrigued me. Seemed quite weird. I figured it out in about ten seconds. How? I simply compiled and ran the shown code in a debugger, and inspected what all the variables are, and what all expressions are really returning, and then the reason for this was very apparent. This is what you should do: learn how to use a debugger to solve puzzles like this. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. It's ok if you are not yet skilled at debugging, everyone has to start somewhere, how about now?

Comment: *since result is of type bool* -- How did you verify this?  How do you know what's behind those `auto` keywords?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) for `std::bitset` returns a [`std::bitset::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) when called on a non-const `std::bitset`. This means the lambda (which deduces the return type), returns a reference to a local variable. This obviously dangles, and invokes undefined behavior when used at the call site.

You can fix this in several ways:

1. Explicitly specify the return type of the lambda, so the reference is converted to `bool` and returned by copy:

```
auto lambda = [](unsigned int param) -> bool
                                     // ^^^^
{   
    std::bitset<10> bits(param);
    std::cout << "inside lambda bits[8] = " << bits[8] << std::endl; 
    return bits[8];
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3zzTrT)

2. Make the `std::bitset` in the lambda `const` so that it calls the `const` overload of `operator[]`, which returns a `bool`:

```
auto lambda = [](unsigned int param)
{   
    std::bitset<10> const bits(param);
                 // ^^^^^
    std::cout << "inside lambda bits[8] = " << bits[8] << std::endl; 
    return bits[8];
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bEnzv6).

3. Store the value of `bits[8]` as a `bool`, and return that:

```
auto lambda = [](unsigned int param)
{   
    std::bitset<10> bits(param);
    std::cout << "inside lambda bits[8] = " << bits[8] << std::endl; 
    bool b = bits[8];
 // ^^^^^^
    return b;
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8jvMcn).